# Java, drilldown an ArrayList of HashMaps

Tags: java, arraylist, drilldown

I have an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`. I'd like to quickly extract from this a new `ArrayList<String>` comprising all the keys.

How do I do this?

Comment: what? You have an ArrayList and you want another ArrayList of keys from an object that doesn't have keys?

Comment: I hadn't formatted the post correctly. Fixed with `   `.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you do

```
List<String> allKeys = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Map<String, String> map : yourListOfMaps)
    allKeys.addAll(map.keySet());
```

If you're not interested in duplicate keys (i.e., if you don't want two identical entries in `allKeys` just because it exists as key in two maps) I would suggest you let `allKeys` be of type `HashSet<String>` instead.

After traversal you could do `allKeysList = new ArrayList<String>(allKeys);` if order is important to you in the end.

Comment: Many thanks for this. What you suggest is certainly good enough for me, but I was also wondering if there is already an analogue of Obj-C's `- (NSMutableArray *)mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath`?